# Реклама в движке Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как можно реализовать в движке unity,рекламу что бы она высвечивалась через определенное количество времени ?

Comment: https://unity.com/ru/solutions/unity-ads
**Что-то такое вроде**
Мне помогало, насколько понял должно помочь

Answer (score 1):

У "рекламщиков" обычно есть специальные библиотеки, которые без труда можно скачать и установить в свой проект, получить API ключ, настроить и радоваться жизни. Нужно всего лишь выбрать подходящую "контору" и внимательно прочитать их инструкции.

- Реклама от самой Unity - [тык](https://unity3d.com/ru/services/ads/quick-start-guide)
- Реклама от Google (AdMob) - [тык](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start)

Comment: Мне собственно нужно это через скрипт провернуть,чтобы показывалась видео реклама а баннер я и сам могу подключить.

Comment: @pr0ger Какой вид рекламы - выбираете сами, но **любой** (будь то банер или видео) вид требует установку небходимых библиотек в проект и получения API (или id) на сайте. Почитайте официальную документацию, там все про это говорится.

Comment: Все библиотеки уже установлены и настроены все API.

Answer (score 0):

### Вы пробовали корутины ?

```
    IEnumerator Name() {
        //сюда пишем код который будет вызывать рекламу
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);//здесь прописано время повтора в секундах
    }
```

Примерно так она выглядит, подробнее можно прочитать в статьях на оф.сайте юнити

- [Здесь](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/Coroutines.html)
- [И здесь](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html)